# Analyse IncidentResolution in Incident

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to analyse the data from the entity *IncidentResolution* with the data from the entity *Incident*. So I just went on analysing the entity *Incident* and tried to make a new view, so I could add the field from *IncidentResolution*, but it is not possible. I think the *IncidentResolution* entity is somewhat linked to the entity *Incident*, but I can't say for sure.

So my question is: **how do I access the data from one entity in another entity?**

What do I need to configure to be able to see the data from the entity *Incident* with the data from *IncidentResolution* together in one line?

btw: sorry if my english is bad, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *IncidentResolution* is a type of Activity.

You can query it via Advanced Find by looking for **Activities** and then setting a condition for `Activity Type = Incident Resolution`. From here you can pull in Case information (for display or filtering) from `Regarding (Case)` in the "Related" section of the field chooser.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that already helped, but there's one thing I am missing: How do I add the row in the advanced search to display the data in the IncidentResolution?

Comment: Oddly enough, you won't be able to get to the IncidentResolution data in the _Results_ grid (but you can get to it in the _Filter_ selections (through related records)). The best you will be able to do is using resolution data exposed through the Incident entity itself (which is limited). If you need to get to IncidentResolution data, you will have to go through a CRM report.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Do you have any sources to the handling with a CRM report?

Comment: You can create a new CRM report using the report wizard with "Activities" and your _Primary Record Group_ and "Case Resolutions" as your _Related Record Group_. This should allow you to report on the Case Resolution fields (outside of going to an SSRS report).